Azure SCIM - Group members are not sending from azure while group provisioning
I perform SCIM provisioning from Azure and have mapped the default attributes in the attribute mapping settings. I added 5 users to the "devtestgroup", but when sending the requests, Azure is only sending the externalId and displayName, and not the members
can someone help me here?
Mapping

Members

Here Members are sending empty

Post method "v1/scim/Groups"
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] Core2Group group)
{
 try
 {
     if (!groups.ContainsKey(group.ExternalIdentifier))
         groups.Add(group.ExternalIdentifier, group);
     return ScimResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, group);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     return ScimError(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
 }
 }


Are you trying to create the group using programatically? Can you please explain you issue bit more

@VivekVaibhavShandilya - No, We are trying to perform on-demand provisioning for the group from Azure, but the members are not being included during provisioning.
